# Django lightweight "update" of huge dataset

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, orm

I have a very large dataset that I need to update as rapidly as possible. I do my calculations and at the end of it have a list of things that need to be updated:

```
updates = [(instance_pk, value_to_update), (instance_pk, value_to_update), ..]
```

The Model is the same throughout, as is the column being updated.

In the past I have used Django Bulk Update —and I'm fairly sure I could here— but even this is ridiculously overpowered (and therefore doing far too much processing, because it handles full instances) for such a simple write that I need to happen fast. Did I mention speed was important here?

Does Django provide *anything* that might make this easier, without needing to write raw SQL?

PostgreSQL 10 is the database, if that turns out to be relevant.

---

I've since tested the raw SQL, which is predictably performant, but here's what it looks like so you're clear what I'm trying to do in-Django.

```
with connection.cursor() as c:
    c.executemany(
        'UPDATE app_model SET column_a = %s WHERE id = %s',
        [(value_to_update, instance_pk), ...]
    )
```

There may be more efficient SQL than execute many (which I think throws *many* queries in one transaction).

Comment: Do you already know what kind of `update` statement you'd like to happen in the database?

Comment: @Kos Updated. Yeah it's pretty simple.

Answer (score 5):

While Kos was writing their excellent answer I was still working on a way to improve my raw-SQL approach, if only to speed things up slightly.

`cursor.executemany()` isn't clever. It just does loads of queries at once. PostsgreSQL has a `UPDATE FROM VALUES(..)` clause but interfacing with it is tricky. Thankfully psycopg2 has a special [`execute_values`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_values) for crafting these value sets, they even document an update example.

If you're using psycopg2+Postgres Django will pass you back the native psycopg2 connection, so this is all really easy to use:

```
from django.db import connection
from psycopg2.extras import execute_values

with connection.cursor() as c:
    execute_values(
        c,
        'UPDATE app_model SET column_a = v.sid FROM (VALUES %s) as v (sid, bid) WHERE id = v.bid',
        [(value_to_update, instance_pk), ...]
    )
```

And it's unimaginably fast. I don't think it's going to get better than this.

Comment: Oh so you don't even need a subquery for `UPDATE ... SET FROM`. Nice.

Comment: Nice answer because I'm a big fan of "low level" database access where appropriate. Don't get me wrong, I think ORMs are awesome, but psycopg2 in particular has several nice extensions that I always use for performance (`copy_*` is another winner...)

Comment: +1 But beware: Django is moving away from psycopg2 with the support for psycopg3 in 4.2. And psycopg3 basically dropped this extra. I'm currently migrating code that depends on this extra and it's no fun.

Answer (score 2):

Given a list of key-value pairs, there's a few ways you can use them to run an UPDATE in SQL:

### Just a lot of queries

```
UPDATE app_model SET column_a = %s WHERE id = %s
UPDATE app_model SET column_a = %s WHERE id = %s
UPDATE app_model SET column_a = %s WHERE id = %s
UPDATE app_model SET column_a = %s WHERE id = %s
```

This is easy to represent in Django:

```
for key, value in updates:
    Model.objects.filter(id=key).update(column_a=value)
```

### One query with cases

```
UPDATE app_model SET column_a = CASE
    WHEN id = %s THEN %s
    WHEN id = %s THEN %s
    WHEN id = %s THEN %s
    WHEN id = %s THEN %s
    ...
WHERE id IN (%s, %s, %s, %s, ...)
```

This is supposed to be faster because the database can find all the rows more efficiently. The query will eventually be super long and I'd suggest to use this approach with batches (say 100 or 1000 rows, do your experiments and see what happens).

In Django you do this either [via the ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/):

```
Model.objects.filter(id__in=ids).update(
    column_a=Case(
        When(id=..., then=Value(...)),
        When(id=..., then=Value(...)),
        When(id=..., then=Value(...)),
        When(id=..., then=Value(...)),
        When(id=..., then=Value(...)),
        ...
    )
)
```

or via the third-party [django-bulk-update](https://github.com/aykut/django-bulk-update) package that does [a similar thing](https://github.com/aykut/django-bulk-update/blob/master/django_bulk_update/helper.py#L163) with a nicer API.

### One query with SELECT FROM

> Note: This is PostgreSQL specific. Other databases might offer other similar SQL extensions.

If you can make a table `data` that contains all the `(key, value)` pairs to update, then you're in a good place for an elegant single-query approach:

```
UPDATE app_model
SET column_a = data.value
FROM data
WHERE app_model.id = data.key;
```

Instead of a table, you should also be able to substitute a subquery if that's easier.

Anyway, I haven't seen a way to build an `UPDATE FROM` query using Django ORM yet, so this requires dropping to raw SQL as far as I can tell.